# Conditionally Display image based on specific text with Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, text, conditional-statements, display

I am constructing a weather website and I would like to use Javascript to display an image conditionally based on a text. The text is a direction (e.g: N, E, S, W) and I would like to show an corresponding image to show the actual direction. The text of wind direction is a parameter `<!--windDirection-->` which cannot be changed and it will only show text only (N, E, S, W). As for the image, it is a Glyphicon instead of a JPG/GIF image. I tested with the following script but nothing happened at all.

```
<script>
function checkwinddircetion() {
    var winddirection = <!--windDirection-->
    var wind = document.getElementById("windd")

    // If the letter is "N"
    if (winddirection.match = "N") {
        windd.class = "wi-wind-default _0-deg";

    // If the letter is "NNE"
    } else if (winddirection.match = "NNE") {
        windd.class = "wi-wind-default _30-deg";

    // If the letter is anything else
    } else {
        windd.class = "wi-wind-default _45-deg font-size-80 text-center";
    }
}
</script>
```

The place for displaying the image is like that and it is not using normal `<img>` tag but using `<i>` tag with specifying the image location in "class":

```
<i name="windd" class=""></i>
```

Anyone know how to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: You don't have an ID set on the i element... only a name

Comment: `winddirection.match = "N"` is wrong. should be `winddirection.match("N")`

Comment: @Yousef_Shamshoum I changed the code to `<i id="windd" class=""></i>` but still not work :(

Comment: @MichaelCoker I changed but still not work :(

`<script>
function checkwinddircetion() {
    var winddirection = <!--windDirection-->
    var wind = document.getElementById("windd")

    // If the letter is "c"
    if (winddirection.match = ("N")) {
        wind.class = "wi-wind-default _0-deg";
        
    // If the letter is "c" or "e"
    } else if (windd.match = ("NNE")) {
        wind.class = "wi-wind-default _30-deg";
        
    // If the letter is anything else
    } else {
        wind.class = "wi-wind-default _45-deg font-size-80 text-center";
    }
}
</script>`

Comment: @Dennis re-read my comment. There is no `=`. And you assign a class you use `windd.className = 'whatever'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<i id="windd" class=""></i>
  --^--(here use id attribute)
<script>
function checkwinddircetion() {
    var winddirection = <!--windDirection-->
     var wind = document.getElementById("windd");
    // If the letter is "N"
    if (winddirection.match(/\bN\b/g)) {
        windd.className = "wi-wind-default _0-deg";
    // If the letter is "NNE"
    } else if (winddirection.match(/\bNNE\b/g)) {
        windd.className = "wi-wind-default _30-deg";
    // If the letter is anything else
    } else {
        windd.className = "wi-wind-default _45-deg font-size-80 text-center";
    }
}
</script>
```

---

```
Note: Add Javascript code after loading markup or at bottom of the page, The document is parsed from top to bottom. Typically, scripts can't find elements which appear later in the markup because those elements haven't yet been added to the DOM.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried your code and it works partly. It works only on the direction of N, E, S and W. Other directions like NNE, NE, ESE, SE... not works. It seems that the script only detect the first letter of the direction, like "ESE" will be treated as "E", "NNE" will be treated as "N" only. Now the code is like this.

Comment: `<script>
function checkwinddircetion() {
    var winddirection = "SE";
    var wind = document.getElementById("windd");
        // If the letter is "N"
    if (winddirection.match("N")) {
        windd.className = "wi-wind-default _0-deg";
    // If the letter is "NNE"
    } else if (winddirection.match("NNE")) {
        windd.className = "wi-wind-default _30-deg";
    // If the letter is "NE"
    } else if (winddirection.match("NE")) {
        windd.className = "wi-wind-default _45-deg";
    } else {
        windd.className = "wi-wind-default _330-deg";
    }
}
</script>`

Comment: I updated my answer, please check and If you want to match complete word,  then use a suitable regular expression winddirection.match(/\bNNE\b/g) . or simply use (==) operator i.e., winddirection=="NNE".

Comment: Letter g at the end of the regular expression performs a global match, and \b metacharacter is used to find a match at the beginning or end of a word.

Comment: Nice! It's totally works and thank you for your great help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code and let me know if it works.

`<i id="windd" onclick="checkwinddircetion()" class="">hello</i>`

You have to click on hello to execute the `checkwinddirection();`

```
function checkwinddircetion() {
    var winddirection = "N";
    var wind = document.getElementById("windd");
        // If the letter is "N"
    if (winddirection.match = "N") {
        windd.setAttribute("class", "wi-wind-default _0-deg");

    // If the letter is "NNE"
    } else if (winddirection.match = "NNE") {
        windd.setAttribute("class","wi-wind-default _30-deg");

    // If the letter is anything else
    } else {
        windd.setAttribute("class","wi-wind-default _45-deg font-size-80 text-center");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

In order to stay within the requirements of OP, I have added a `switch()` to handle 8 conditions that swap out 8 classes. The condition is the real number value of user input from `#direction` (i.e. `<input>`). The result is a text indicating one of the 8 cardinal points of direction: `N`, `NE`, `E`, `SE`, `S`, `SW`, `W`, `NW`

The `<input>`is added for demonstration purposes. Basically, you'd have more flexibility if you dealt with numbers* for the degrees rather than classes. If you wanted an accurate direction, you'd need to somehow have the capability to create and manipulate 360 classes dynamically.

Using a simple expression, you can rotate your wind vane 360 degrees without using classes.

*variable input aren't real numbers but strings that represent numbers.

**BASIC CODE**

> ```
>   <i id='needle' class='fa fa-arrow-up'></i>
>   var pnt = document.getElementById('needle');
>   var news = '270';
>   pnt.style.transform = 'rotate(' + news + 'deg)';
> ```

That's West

Details are commented in Snippet

**SNIPPET**

```js
// Reference the number <input>
var dir = document.getElementById('direction');

// When user inputs data into #direction call windVane
dir.addEventListener('input', windVane, false);


function windVane(e) {
  // Reference the <nav>
  var wv = document.getElementById('windVane');

  // Reference the <i>con
  var pnt = document.getElementById('needle');

  // Store the value of #direction's data in a var
  var news = this.value;

  // Convert news into a real number
  var deg = parseInt(news, 10);

  /* Rotate #needle as many degrees as the value
  || of the variable news has from #direction
  */
  pnt.style.transform = 'rotate(' + news + 'deg)';


  /* This switch passes in deg which stores the real
  || numbers of current direction #needle points to.
  || There are 8 cardinal points repesented as a class.
  || When the value of deg changes, so does the text
  || of the pseudo-element of #windVane.
  */
  // One breakdown of a step explained 
  switch (true) {
    case (deg === 360 || deg === 0):
      wv.className = '';
      wv.classList.add('n');
      break;
    case (deg < 90):
      wv.className = '';
      wv.classList.add('ne');
      break;
    case (deg === 90):
      wv.className = '';
      wv.classList.add('e');
      break;
      // If deg is less than 180...
    case (deg < 180):
      // Remove #windVane's class
      wv.className = '';
      // Add the .se class to #windVane
      wv.classList.add('se');
      // Go no further down this switch loop is done
      break;
    case (deg === 180):
      wv.className = '';
      wv.classList.add('s');
      break;
    case (deg < 270):
      wv.className = '';
      wv.classList.add('sw');
      break;
    case (deg === 270):
      wv.className = '';
      wv.classList.add('w');
      break;
    case (deg < 360):
      wv.className = '';
      wv.classList.add('nw');
      break;
    default:
      wv.className = '';
      wv.classList.add('n');
      break;
  }

}
```

```css
#windVane {
  margin: 1ch 1ch 0 0;
  font: 400 16px/1 Times;
}
/* 8 Cardinal Points 
|| These pseudo-elements will activate upon
|| the condition of degrees #needle is at
*/

#windVane.n::after {
  content: 'N';
}
#windVane.ne::after {
  content: 'NE';
}
#windVane.e::after {
  content: 'E';
}
#windVane.se::after {
  content: 'SE';
}
#windVane.s::after {
  content: 'S';
}
#windVane.sw::after {
  content: 'SW';
}
#windVane.w::after {
  content: 'W';
}
#windVane.nw::after {
  content: 'NW';
}
#needle {
  font-size: 4ch;
}
input {
  width: 5ch;
  font: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!--Using Font-Awesome for arrow icon; it's like GlyphIcon
----on steroids-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!--This number input is to simulate the data input that 
----your app would use-->
<label for='needle'>Enter a number (max.360):</label>
<input id='direction' type='number' min='0' max='360' step='1'>

<!--#windVane contains #needle and displays a text of 
----what direction #needle is pointing to. #needle is 
----your icon which by means of the tranform:rotate css
----property we will able to turn it all 360 degrees. 
----Make sure your <i>con has an id to reference-->
<nav id='windVane' class='n'>
  <i id='needle' class='fa fa-arrow-up'></i>
</nav>
```